# How to send cluster in separated node ros pcl

Tags: ros, point-cloud-library

Hi i'm new in pointcloud library. I'm trying to show clustering result point on rviz or pcl viewer, and then show nothing. And i realize that my data show nothing too when i subcsribe and cout that. Hopefully can help my problem, thanks

This is my code for clustering and send node

```
void cloudReceive(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud2ConstPtr& inputMsg){
mutex_lock.lock();
pcl::fromROSMsg(*inputMsg, *inputCloud);
cout<<inputCloud<<endl;
pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr tree (new pcl::search::KdTree<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
tree->setInputCloud(inputCloud);

std::vector<pcl::PointIndices> cluster_indices;
pcl::EuclideanClusterExtraction<pcl::PointXYZRGB> ec;

ec.setClusterTolerance(0.03);//2cm
ec.setMinClusterSize(200);//min points
ec.setMaxClusterSize(1000);//max points
ec.setSearchMethod(tree);
ec.setInputCloud(inputCloud);
ec.extract(cluster_indices);

if(cluster_indices.size() > 0){
    std::vector<pcl::PointIndices>::const_iterator it;

    int i = 0;

    for (it = cluster_indices.begin(); it != cluster_indices.end(); ++it){
        if(i >= 10)
            break;

        cloud_cluster[i]->points.clear();
        std::vector<int>::const_iterator idx_it;

        for (idx_it = it->indices.begin(); idx_it != it->indices.end(); idx_it++)
            cloud_cluster[i]->points.push_back(inputCloud->points[*idx_it]);

        cloud_cluster[i]->width = cloud_cluster[i]->points.size();
        // cloud_cluster[i]->height = 1;
        // cloud_cluster[i]->is_dense = true;

        cout<<"PointCloud representing the Cluster: " << cloud_cluster[i]->points.size() << " data points"<<endl;
        std::stringstream ss;
        ss<<"cobaa_pipecom2_cluster_"<< i << ".pcd";
        writer.write<pcl::PointXYZRGB> (ss.str(), *cloud_cluster[i], false);

        pcl::toROSMsg(*cloud_cluster[i], outputMsg);
        // cout<<"data = "<< outputMsg <<endl;
        cloud_cluster[i]->header.frame_id = FRAME_ID;
        pclpub[i++].publish(outputMsg);

        // i++;
    }
}
else
   ROS_INFO_STREAM("0 clusters extracted\n");
```

}

And this one is the main

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){

for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
    // std::cout << " - clustering/" << z << std::endl;

    cloud_cluster[z] = pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
    cloud_cluster[z]->height = 1;
    cloud_cluster[z]->is_dense = true;
    // cloud_cluster[z]->header.frame_id = FRAME_ID;
}

ros::init(argc,argv,"clustering");
ros::NodeHandlePtr nh(new ros::NodeHandle());
pclsub = nh->subscribe("/pclsegmen",1,cloudReceive);

std::string pub_str("clustering/0");

for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
    pub_str[11] = z + 48;//48=0(ASCII)
    // z++;
    pclpub[z] = nh->advertise <sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> (pub_str, 1);
}

// pclpub = nh->advertise<sensor_msgs::PointCloud2>("/pclcluster",1);
ros::spin();
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is, i change the ASCII number into lexical_cast. Thanks for your response, i hope this can help other

```
    for (int z = 0; z < CLOUD_QTD; z++) {
    // pub_str[11] = z + 48;
    std::string topicName = "/pclcluster/" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(z);
    global::pub[z] = n.advertise <sensor_msgs::PointCloud2> (topicName, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an exact answer, but I think it addresses your issue & may ease your debugging. 
RViz can directly subscribe to a published point cloud, the one I'm assuming you're trying to see in the cloud_receive callback. If you set the Frame to whichever frame it's being published at, and add it from the available topics, you should see the points. (Easier than trying to rebroadcast it as different topics).

Also, I recommend looking at the [`rostopic`](https://wiki.ros.org/rostopic) command line tool. You can do `rostopic list` to check if it's being published, `rostopic bw` to see if it's really publishing the expected volume of data (ex bytes vs kilobytes vs megabytes), `rostopic hz` to see how frequently (if ever) it's publishing, and (briefly) `rostopic echo` to look at the data itself. (This is me assuming from your question it's more an issue with the data coming into your node).

If you're having trouble, not with data coming into the node, nor with the visualization of pointcloud data in general, but with the transformed data that's supposed to come out of the node, I would check that the clustering worked, & reduce your code moreso to just having 1 publisher publish something. You may be doing something weird. Like messing up your pointers. You could also turn on stronger compilation warnings for your node with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror` or step through the execution of it [via gdb](https://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/Tutorials/Roslaunch%20Nodes%20in%20Valgrind%20or%20GDB) (`launch-prefix="xterm -e gdb --args"`).

Comment: Thanks for your help, i'll give it a try
Anyway my topic shown when i give rostopic list